# Go to specific section when button clicked in flutter

Tags: flutter, web

I am trying to navigate the section on the same page when the button is clicked but I can not do it using PageView and Scroll, Does anyone know how to do it?

[image]

This is the navigation bar on the top of the page and I want it to go to specific section on the same page when the button is clicked.
this is my code:

```
     Row(
              children: [
                NavItem(
                  title: 'Home',
                  onPreesed: () {},
                  color: KprimaryColor,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                ),
                NavItem(
                  title: 'About',
                  onPreesed: () {},
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                ),
                NavItem(
                  title: 'Projects',
                  onPreesed: () {},
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                ),
                NavItem(
                  title: 'Contact',
                  onPreesed: () {},
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, try this!

```
class MyAppTabView extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: DefaultTabController(
        length: 4,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            title: Text('Flutter Tabs', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
            bottom: const PreferredSize(
              preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(40),
              child: Align(
                alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                child: TabBar(
                    isScrollable: true,
                    unselectedLabelStyle: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
                    unselectedLabelColor: Colors.black,
                    indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label,
                    indicatorColor: Colors.transparent,
                    labelColor: Colors.red,
                    labelStyle: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    tabs: [
                      Tab(
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                          child: Center(
                            child: Text("Home"),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Tab(
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                          child: Center(
                            child: Text("About"),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Tab(
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                          child: Center(
                            child: Text("Projects"),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Tab(
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                          child: Center(
                            child: Text("Contact"),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ]),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          body: TabBarView(
            children: [
              Center(child: Text("Home")),
              Center(child: Text("About")),
              Center(child: Text("Projects")),
              Center(child: Text("Contact")),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Enjoy Coding!!

Comment: Thank you, but is this code to create an app bar? Because am not looking for navigation app bar cuz I already did it.

Comment: Mention Not!
Please check may be It will help you, it works same as shown in image!
Thank you!